# WebSphere Liberty integration with Redis for HTTP Session Persistence

Tags: redis, websphere-liberty, redisson, jcache

We are trying to replace WebSphere Extremescape in our environment and planning to use redis. The only reason we are using WebSphere extremescale is to provide HTTP session persistence. I believe we can use jcache/redisson to have WebSphere Liberty use redis for session persistence. Has anyone done that - if yes, would you please share your configuration for redisson-jcache.yaml and server.xml configuration

Thanks,

Here is the stack trace

```
[3/27/24 1:04:12:216 UTC] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl              
I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Default configuration hasn't been specified! com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheHashMap 250" at ffdc_24.03.27_01.04.11.0.log
[3/27/24 1:04:12:218 UTC] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheHashMap                 
 E SESN0307E: An exception occurred when initializing the cache.
 The exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default configuration hasn't been specified!
        at org.redisson.jcache.JCacheManager.createCache(JCacheManager.java:119)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheHashMap.cacheInit(CacheHashMap.java:192)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheHashMap.lambda$new$0(CacheHashMap.java:136)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:690)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheHashMap.<init>(CacheHashMap.java:135)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheStore.<init>(CacheStore.java:35)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.cache.CacheStoreService.createStore(CacheStoreService.java:323)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.createStore(SessionContext.java:355)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.createStore(SessionContext.java:344)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.createCoreSessionManager(SessionContext.java:257)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.createCoreSessionManager(SessionContext.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.impl.HttpSessionContextImpl.createCoreSessionManager(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:963)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.<init>(SessionContext.java:160)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.<init>(SessionContext.java:145)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.impl.HttpSessionContextImpl.<init>(HttpSessionContextImpl.java:61)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.impl.SessionContextRegistryImpl.createSessionContextObject(SessionContextRegistryImpl.java:98)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.impl.SessionContextRegistryImpl.createSessionContext(SessionContextRegistryImpl.java:86)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.impl.SessionContextRegistryImpl.getSessionContext(SessionContextRegistryImpl.java:309)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.getSessionContext(WebContainer.java:707)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHost.getSessionContext(VirtualHost.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.getSessionContext(WebGroup.java:158)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.createSessionContext(WebApp.java:1344)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationStart(WebApp.java:1327)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationStart(WebApp.java:256)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1039)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6705)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:474)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:469)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1197)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$100(WebContainer.java:112)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$3.run(WebContainer.java:994)
        at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:247)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
.
```

Comment: Here is Liberty part [Configuring Liberty session persistence with JCache](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=manually-configuring-liberty-session-persistence-jcache)

Comment: Thank you. IBM support had pointed me to the same page, though the information mentioned there is not redisson specific. I am unclear on how the redisson-jcache.yaml needs to be constructed. Also, do I just take the redisson java client jar file and put it on the shared folder for Liberty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redisson for JCache Session persistence on WebSphere-Liberty: how to pass redisson-jcache.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409853/redisson-for-jcache-session-persistence-on-websphere-liberty-how-to-pass-rediss)

Comment: Thanks, again. I saw this article earlier. I see that it has been mark resolved and I was hoping that someone could share their configuration, especially the redisson-jcache.yaml file.

Comment: Added the stack trace to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there is issue in your config, so add your yaml to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so just to briefly summarize the other answer:

Add feature:

```
<feature>sessionCache-1.0</feature>
```

Define library:

```
<library id="jCacheVendorLib">
  <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/redisson" includes="*"/>
</library>
```

Use library in cache config:

```
    <httpSessionCache libraryRef="jCacheVendorLib"
                      uri="file:${shared.resource.dir}/redisson/redisson-jcache.yaml" />
```

Contents of the redisson-jcache.yaml:

```
clusterServersConfig:
  password: ${clusterServerConfig.password}
  nodeAddresses:
  - ${clusterServerConfig.nodeAddresses}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your persistent and prompt replies. One last question - I assume I can have only one configuration in the redisson-jcache yaml file. I assume the name clusterServersConfig has a special meaning. Similarly, there must be a name when using a single server configuration.

Comment: Yes, look at the documentation and pick matching config - https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/Table-of-Content

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much!! I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: Would you know what jar files are needed for redisson? I downloaded redisson-3.27.2.jar file and placed it in the shared resources directory. I am getting an error in the log file saying "org.redisson.jcache.JCachingProvider could not be instantiated".

Comment: I had to copy another jar file. Now, I am getting the same error that was mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409853/redisson-for-jcache-session-persistence-on-websphere-liberty-how-to-pass-rediss link. I am using a single server config in the yaml file.

Comment: Edit your question with the detailed error message, or paste it in the comments.

Comment: Here is the stack trace

Comment: I believe I am almost there. I see the following [3/27/24 13:59:56:871 UTC] 0000002a io.openliberty.jcache.internal.CacheManagerServiceImpl       I CWLJC0005I: The default-0 JCache CacheManager took 92 ms to load.

[3/27/24 13:59:56:872 UTC] 0000002b io.openliberty.jcache.internal.CacheManagerServiceImpl       I CWLJC0005I: The CacheManager JCache CacheManager took 83 ms to load.

Comment: I see it is working now. Thank you so much for all the help! I am now trying to see if I can get it working with SSL-enabled redis. Would you know if we need to make any specific changes for SSL?

Comment: You will need to add Redis cert to the liberty ssl trust store (in short).

Comment: Thank you! I got it working with SSL too. Thanks a ton for all the help. It would have taken me a lot longer without all the help.